# Unity Understanding Intercepted Events

Tags: unity-game-engine

Google isn't very helpful.

I am new to Unity.

What is an Intercepted event? How do I get rid of it? Why do I have them in the first place?

Thank you

Comment: How is an Intercepted event bothering you? Show us some code or elaborate on your issue. Your question now is too vague.

Comment: All I want to know is what is the purpose of having them. The purpose of a restaurant menu is to show the different types of items you can have for lunch. The purpose of an intercepted event is ? Like that's all I want to know. Just a general description, I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the Editor area titled Intercepted events those are just events which the control listens to.
https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html